# Reading mp3 track duration on Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

On Android I am getting this error `Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException`:

> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2058/58099c53/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.m__0 (object) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2058/58099c53/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1006
>   at Android.App.SyncContext/c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2058/58099c53/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:18
>   at Java.Lang.Thread/RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2058/58099c53/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36
>   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (intptr,intptr) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2058/58099c53/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:71
>   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.7dac782f-30e4-45cb-a248-e0c4c79fbcad (intptr,intptr)
>
> --- End of managed exception stack trace --- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException   at
>   android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:169) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

using this code to retrive *.mp3 file duration:

```
public async Task<string> GetTrackDuration(string pathToFile)
{
    MediaMetadataRetriever reader = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    await reader.SetDataSourceAsync (global::Android.App.Application.Context, Android.Net.Uri.Parse (pathToFile));

    return reader.ExtractMetadata(MetadataKey.Duration).ToString();
}
```

where is the problem? I have tried all of the posible constructors

Comment: The set data source is set correctly? you can try also with reader.SetDataSource (String pathToFile);

Comment: Why you are setting the Context like this and not like the usual way? Android.Content.Context currentContext? I dont know if this is the problem although im just wondering

Comment: Like I said, I tried also this `reader.SetDataSource (pathToFile);` without success, `sync` or `async` it doesn't matter, probably the problem is somewhere else ;/